# How to do cURL PUT requests with a php://memory file handle?

Tags: php, curl, filehandle

I'm using a 3rd party PHP class to access an API, it has got the following code:

```
$fh = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');
fwrite($fh, $xml);
rewind($fh);
$ch = curl_init($req->to_url() );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
```

On the last line, i.e this one:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
```

I'm getting the error:

> Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: cannot represent a
>   stream of type MEMORY as a STDIO FILE*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `CURLOPT_INFILE` defines an "_input_ file" (not "_into_ file"), that is probably not, what you are looking for, especially because `$fh` is open for writing.

Comment: I got this with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fh);`, using `temp` fixed it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your Memory File Handle is only open for writing (w+). Add reading, e.g. try to set `rw+` for the file handle.

An alternative would be to use `php://temp` instead of memory. That would write to a temporary file if there isn't enough memory available.